# ¿Cómo mantener un método en ejecución?

Tags: java

Tengo 2 iconos, y quiero que vayan cambiando cada segundo. También quiero que se ejecute siempre y no se detenga. Lo estoy haciendo con este código pero no tengo éxito.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Timer timer = new Timer();

        JFrameLeds jframeLeds = new JFrameLeds();
        jframeLeds.setVisible(true);

        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Icon icono;

                icono = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("camera.png"));
                jframeLeds.jLabel1.setIcon(icono);



                icono = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("target.png"));
                jframeLeds.jLabel1.setIcon(icono);
            }
        };

        timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 1000);
    }
```

Comment: mmm.. no se ejecuta una sola vez.. pero hace siempre lo mismo.. lo que es lo mismo que si se ejecutara una sola vez.. que intentabas hacer?

Comment: Ya edite bien la pregunta amigo @gbianchi :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explico el porque no te funciona:
La imagen al estar bajo la otra en el mismo método y al mismo tiempo se pisan entre si en todas las ejecuciones que realiza el `Timer`, te sugiero cambiar el path de la imagen en cada llamada al método `run()` que en tu caso es cada segundo de la siguiente forma:

```
// Debes poner tus imagenes en un array
String[] arr = {"camera.png", "target.png"};
TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask()
{
    // La siguiente variable se encarga de recorrer las imagenes cada vez que cambia su indice en este caso "+1"
    int indexImage = 0;
    public void run() 
    {
        jLabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/" + arr[indexImage])));
        jLabel1.repaint();
        indexImage++;
        // Se verifica si llegó a la ultima imagen y se vuelve a comenzar con el indice en 0
        if (indexImage == arr.length)
            indexImage = 0;
    }
};
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 1000);
```

Comment: Aunque esto es correcto podrias explicar cual fue el error de OP y tambien porque tu codigo lo resuelve y como?

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, te sugerimos revisar [answer], saludos.

Comment: Ok, lo tomo en cuenta

Comment: Me sale java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @GianFrancoAlexisPomaVidal para ese error hay una pregunta al respecto. busca eso mismo en el sitio y vas a saber porque pasa

Comment: Posiblemente el error sea porque para el ejemplo yo puse `.getResource("/images/" + arr[indexImage])` ya que yo tengo mis imagenes en la carpeta `images/`, en este caso tu tienes que poner el path de tus imagenes si no me equivoco `.getResource("/" + arr[indexImage])`

Comment: así es, me quede pensando unos minutos y fue por eso, gracias :)